# Left arrow doesn't work on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, stretch

Yesterday I installed Debian Stretch although some bugs the system work correctly but there is a really annoying bug: My left arrow doesn't work, the system not receive input since the installation procedure, I don't know how resolve this problem, actually my keyboard it's set to generic 101 keys, the same number of keys of my laptop, I hope that someone will help me, my laptop is a Samsung R530 JA50IT and its keyboard work correctly with other Debian version like Jessie (8) or other Linux distro.

Comment: The keyboard mapping sounds like it's messed up. Redo your mapping setup.

Comment: Or, check with `xev` how your left arrow is decoded, if at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify whether this problem occurs on a virtual console, in X11, or both.  The answer will differ depending on which kind of input is affected.